# Is conditional awaiting misleading?

Tags: javascript, async-await, code-readability

Consider the following two code snippets (assumed to be inside an `async` function that returns void / we don't care about the return value):

Long version (without `await`):

```js
if (condition) {
    conditionalCodeBlock.then(unconditionalCodeBlock);
} else {
    unconditionalCodeBlock;
}
```

Short version (with `await`):

```js
if (condition) {
    await conditionalCodeBlock;
}
unconditionalCodeBlock;
```

Both code snippets do the same thing. The short version doesn't have to repeat `unconditionalCodeBlock` in the two cases, but it somewhat hides the fact that `unconditionalCodeBlock` is being invoked in different ways: asynchronously if `condition` is true, and asynchronously if false.

My colleague thinks that sweeping this complexity under the rug can be misleading and make it harder to reason about the code, so he prefers the longer version.

Is this concern valid: Does this matter in practice (and in what situations), and if so, there is a way to address this concern this without having to repeat `unconditionalCodeBlock`?

---

(Some more background on how this question arose, and illustration/verification of how async works in this case, are in the  edit history ([second revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77870459/2)) of this question.)

Comment: without reading all that, personally, I'd always use `Short version with await:` - but that's an opinion, as is the wall of justification after that first bit of your question

Answer (score 2):

> It's invoked asynchronously if true and synchronously if false. A colleague pointed out that sweeping this complexity under the rug can be misleading and make it harder to reason about the code, so his preference would be for the more verbose first way.

Neither syntax is better or less misleading.

The actual problem is that by executing the block sometimes-synchronously sometimes-asynchronously there is potential to be mislead at all. Don't make it hard to reason about in the first place! In the majority of cases, it actually doesn't matter for any reasoning whether the code executes synchronously or not. If that is the case, you can choose either syntax, and you'd prefer the shorter and simpler one, in particular without the repetition.

However if you have one of the rare cases where it matters for reasoning, you should strife towards making reasoning easier by consistently executing the code **always asynchronously** and thereby [avoiding zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony). In your example, that might be

```
// guarantee that `unconditionalCodeBlock` is executed asynchronously
await (condition
  ? conditionalCodeBlock
  : undefined
);
unconditionalCodeBlock;
```

<sup>(the comment is important so that someone doesn't optimise the `await` away by cleaning up this slightly weird code, and breaks the assumptions you've made or even the guarantees you've documented for your API)</sup>

If that isn't possible either and you absolutely need to sometimes execute the code synchronously for whatever reason, formatting still won't help you. You have to add a comment where you clearly state this reason, and where you lay down the reasoning about (a)sync execution that you've already done yourself.